# How to set different default cell per section?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, cells

In various sections in my notebook I'd like the default cell type to be different, if possible, how can I specify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to my understanding of Kuba's comments below the question  [`DefaultNewCellStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultNewCellStyle.html) is a supported option for individual Cells.  For example you can create a Notebook with three Chapters, each with a different default cell style:

```
CreateDocument[{
  Cell["New cells are Input", "Chapter", DefaultNewCellStyle -> "Input"],
  Cell["New cells are Text", "Chapter", DefaultNewCellStyle -> "Text"],
  Cell["New cells are Code", "Chapter", DefaultNewCellStyle -> "Code"]
}]
```

Now creating cells under each section merely by typing at the insertion point (horizontal line):

[image]

You can set the Option using the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) or programmatically as above.

Comment: I forgot for a minute to not trust documentation and this is what happens.

Comment: @Kuba touché! :^)